# MySQL how to compare list of strings with subquery

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that can match a list of strings on a subquery.
Example

TableA

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | somevalue1 |
| 2 | somevalue2 |

TableB

| id | value | tableA_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 |
| 2 | test2 | 1 |
| 3 | test1 | 2 |

I need a query that returns all the entries from TableA who have an entry in TableB for a list of strings.

For:

```
select * from TableA ta where ('test1', 'test2') = (select tb.value from TableB tb where tb.tableA_id = ta.id);
```

Expected result would be

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | somevalue1 |

because this is the only entry in TableA that has entries for both those string values in TableB.

I tried to look on the internet on how to match a list of string in MySQL but didn't found something that I can use, my sql skills are at beginner level.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you may not even need to involve `TableA` in this query.  I suggest the following canonical aggregation approach on `TableB`:

```sql
SELECT tableA_id
FROM TableB
WHERE value IN ('test1', 'test2')
GROUP BY tableA_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2;
```